# How to inject a config setting into a custom RavenDB bundle

Tags: ravendb

I have hardcoded an SQL Server connection string into a RequestResponder.  What is the recommended way of getting the config into the RequestResponder in a way that could work in both Debug and Release?

Is it recommended to use MEF or Database.Configuration such as:

```
var connectionString = database.Configuration.GetConfigurationValue<string>("MySettings/ConnectionString")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use either an appSettings value or putting the config inside a RavenDB doc.